# Is there a way to minimize the size of a CloudFront image response?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to find ways to reduce the cost of Amazon CloudFront and when hitting an image URL, I get a bunch of response headers that some, make no sense to be sent over, and I'm then trying to figure out a way to reduce the size of the response

I already compress the image automagically using a Lamdba function together with [Tinify API](https://tinypng.com/developers) and I would love to know how to reduce the header response

The current response headers are:

[image]

while the AWS S3 Bucket CORS setup is as

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Content-Length</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

on the Cloudfront behavior side:

[image]

How can I control the headers that are being sent, so I can minimize the response?

BTW, we have 160 billion requests a month, and the price is up to 900 USD/mo.

Answer (score 0):

using [lambda@Edge](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-how-it-works-tutorial.html) I could remove the custom headers, but that was it... it still sends the `X-Amz...` and `X-Cache` headers that make no sense to a browser to receive

here's the result from 20 minutes research:

[image]

he lamdba@edge function content:

```js
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
    const headers = response.headers;

    // console.log('before', JSON.stringify(headers).length, JSON.stringify(headers));
    
    /*
    {
        "x-amz-id-2": [
            {
                "key": "x-amz-id-2",
                "value": "XTGarjTktp+kDnYOCGbYkxDYLSZ9zHhUga6QSTNGhnqCuEgFRRvHsMcf0RbjrO6wsmX9NblckO0="
            }
        ],
        "x-amz-request-id": [
            {
                "key": "x-amz-request-id",
                "value": "E2FC8989DE42B358"
            }
        ],
        "date": [
            {
                "key": "Date",
                "value": "Thu, 30 Jul 2020 07:22:54 GMT"
            }
        ],
        "last-modified": [
            {
                "key": "Last-Modified",
                "value": "Mon, 27 Jul 2020 13:12:59 GMT"
            }
        ],
        "etag": [
            {
                "key": "ETag",
                "value": "\"115bbd98a61b665346d0b497f52cc94a\""
            }
        ],
        "x-amz-meta-cache-control": [
            {
                "key": "x-amz-meta-cache-control",
                "value": "max-age=604800"
            }
        ],
        "cache-control": [
            {
                "key": "Cache-Control",
                "value": "max-age=604800"
            }
        ],
        "x-amz-meta-file-compressed": [
            {
                "key": "x-amz-meta-file-compressed",
                "value": "Mon Jul 27 2020 13:12:58 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)"
            }
        ],
        "accept-ranges": [
            {
                "key": "Accept-Ranges",
                "value": "bytes"
            }
        ],
        "server": [
            {
                "key": "Server",
                "value": "AmazonS3"
            }
        ],
        "content-type": [
            {
                "key": "Content-Type",
                "value": "image/png"
            }
        ],
        "content-length": [
            {
                "key": "Content-Length",
                "value": "73432"
            }
        ]
    }
    */

    // delete extra headers
    delete headers['age'];
    delete headers['via'];
    delete headers['connection'];
    delete headers['server'];
    delete headers['x-cache'];
    delete headers['x-amz-cf-pop'];
    delete headers['x-amz-cf-id'];
    delete headers['x-amz-meta-cache-control'];
    delete headers['x-amz-meta-file-compressed'];
    
    delete headers['x-amz-id-2'];
    delete headers['x-amz-request-id'];
    delete headers['etag'];
    
    // console.log('after', JSON.stringify(headers).length, JSON.stringify(headers));

    return response;
};
```

so we went from **72.33Kb** to **72.15Kb**, that's **0.18Kb reduction** ... let's hope the cost of the lambda function running does not pass the cost we're saving

Lambda running report:

```
REPORT RequestId: 433e05a2-fb70-45a5-9773-92f024d5f05c Duration: 3.94 ms Billed Duration: 50 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 65 MB Init Duration: 146.52 ms
```

Comment: That is a 0.18kB reduction, or 0.24%, saving less than $3 of $900.  Depending on how you measured it, the real reduction is likely even less, because HTTP/2 has header compression.  I wouldn't recommend this approach.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot The idea was to remove all other headers... but somehow I simply can't ... will send AWS a support ticket, maybe there's a way ... makes no sense to send to the browser the `Age`, `Via`, `X-Amz-Cf-Pop` and `X-Amz-Cf-Id` ... it is useful only when we're debugging something... what do you suggest?

Comment: You do realize that with your stated traffic volume of 160 billion requests per month, and a price of $0.60 per million invocations of Lambda@Edge, this solution will cost you $96,000 per month? Seems like false economy to me.

Comment: true, hence checking other ways ... I'm just testing for the free 1M requests :)